# ADPlus.exe with Windows debugging tools - what's funcationlity difference if compare to ADPlus vbscript

Tags: adplus

I have installed the new version of Windows debugging tools and I got a AdPlus.exe. I don't know if there are any changes but I remember when I installed it sometime ago on another computer, what i got was a ADPlus as vbscript file ( and not an executable). In the installation directory I still see there is a vbscript file but does any one know what is the difference between executable and vbscript. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/whatsnew.mspx) "what's new" article, they seem to be pretty much the same in that the vbs can still be used if you don't have .net framework 2.0 installed on the machine. That's not to say that there isn't something extra in the tool. You could find out by checking out adplus.doc in that same folder.